# Terminate an HTML script element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My site has a page loading system to load only the necessary content of the next page that the user is navigating to, and it keeps the top navigation and footer, and only fetches the new content. In order to execute the script tags that are in the new HTML content that's loaded with `fetch()`, all the script tags are appended with `document.body.appendChild(scriptElementToRun)`. The script elements are added to an array so that they can be removed when the user navigates to another page which will require different scripts. The problem is that removing the script elements from the DOM is not enough to terminate them. They still continue to execute. Is it possible to stop the execution of only the scripts that are in the array, even asynchronous code such as setInterval, setTimout, WebSockets etc. that don't run in the main event loop, without adding anything to the script tags I want to stop?

This is the code that adds the scripts:

```
let result = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(data); // decode the binary response data
$('mn').innerHTML = result; // a div that contains the main body content of the page
for (script of $('mn').getElementsByTagName('script')) {
    let activeScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    pageScripts.push(activeScriptElement);
    if (script.src) {
        activeScriptElement.src = script.src;
        console.log('run script: ' + script.src);
    } else { // inline script
        activeScriptElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(script.innerHTML));
        console.log('run script: inline');
    }
    document.body.appendChild(activeScriptElement);
}
```

I then remove the scripts when loading a new page:

```
for (script of pageScripts){
    script.remove();
}
```

EDIT:
What I ended up doing is putting all the page HTML content in an iFrame and communicating between the iFrame and the parent window with window.postMessage()

Answer (score -1):

It would be helpful to see the code you're talking about. I'm guessing that you are using event listeners, which will still be active, even if you remove script-tags from the DOM.

You can remove events like this:

```
document.getElementById("your-elements-id").removeEventListener();

var myTimeout = setTimeout(...);
clearTimeout(myTimeout);

var myInterval = setInterval(...);
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Comment: I've added the relevant code. I'm not only talking about event listeners, I'm talking about setTimeout, setInterval, WebSocket connections and other callback functions. I need a way to cancel all of them without knowing what's inside the script tag.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no all-in-one solution to just kill off all these scripts.
setTimeout() and setInterval() can be removed like this (see answer).

Comment: I was hoping there was an all-in-one solution, because I need to stop everything without knowing what functions are running in the other script tags and therefore there's no way I could possibly utilize clearInterval() or ws.close() etc.

Comment: Refreshing the page is not an option?

Comment: The thing is I don't want the main scripts that are supposed to run on all pages to stop running and the pages load so much faster when I do it this way.